# SQL Query - select youngest author at the moment of his first publishing

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join, greatest-n-per-group

I can't get my head around this.
I have 3 tables in a database.

Authors

```
authodId  | name |  birthDate | country  
----------|------|------------|--------  
1         | name1|  3.02.1940 | USA
```

Books

```
title  | bookId | Publisher   | Year | nrofpages | price  
-------|--------|-------------|------|-----------|--------  
title1 | 1      | publisher1  | 2009 | 200       |20
```

BooksAuthors

```
bookId | authorNumber | AuthorId  
-------|--------------|------------  
1      | 1            | 1
```

My questing is, how do I get the youngest author at the moment of his first publishing?

This is all a got so far and I'm stuck:

```
SELECT *
FROM Authors au INNER JOIN
     BooksAuthors ba
     ON au.authorid = ba.authorid INNER JOIN
     Books bo
     ON ba.bookid = bo.bookid
```

I am sorry for the bad formatting. I don't post here a lot.

Comment: Calculate the difference between the year a book was published and  the year of the birthdate and order by it. If the are multiple authors with that minimum age you can additionaly order by descending month/day

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query

```
SELECT *
FROM Authors A 
INNER JOIN BooksAuthors BA ON A.authorid = BA.authorid 
INNER JOIN Books B ON B.bookid = BA.bookid 
ORDER BY DATEDIFF(HOUR, A.birthdate, B.year) ASC
```